# How can I give an ID to CancellationToken?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, cancellation-token

I have a system that links tokens received from different places. Then, it uses this merged token to perform some task. The final merged token can consist of 5 different tokens.

While the task is running, I can call `cancellationTokenSource.Cancel()` in any of the places where the `CancellationTokenSource` came from for the merge. Then the exception is caught using `try-catch`, and a message is printed to the console.

```
catch (Exception ex) {
    if (ex is TaskCanceledException taskCanceledException) {
        var token = taskCanceledException.CancellationToken;
        Console.WriteLine("Task was canceled via token. " 
            + "Where and when it was created? Idk.");
    }
}
```

I came across a bug where an old canceled token is still in use, and I have no idea where and when it was created. I could enter this information into the name of the token, which I would then take out from the exception and print in the console.

However, the token does not have such a field.

How do people using CancellationToken-s deal with debugging these situations?

Comment: Are you aware that the `TaskCanceledException` derives from the `OperationCanceledException`, which has a [`CancellationToken`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.operationcanceledexception.cancellationtoken) property?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias So? Does `CancellationToken` have a `string Label {get;set}` where I could enter my custom ID?

Comment: It hasn't. if you want to associate tokens with labels, you have to maintain a `Dictionary<CancellationToken, string>` somewhere.